# Mongodb C# driver - Update document then select collection with updated document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm updating a document in Mongodb with the C# driver.  I've verified the update is successfully completing, but if I select the collection that contains the updated document immediately after the update I'm not seeing the new values immediately.  If I put a breakpoint in my code after the update but before the select, I will see the new values in the results from the Select.  If I let the code run straight through, I get the old values in my names collection.  I tried changing the write concern, but I don't think that's it.  Is there some way to chain these two operations together so the select won't happen until the update has completed?

```
var qry = Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(id));
var upd = Update.Set("age", BsonValue.Create(newAge));

db.GetCollection<MongoTest>("mongotest").Update(qry,upd);

... would like to pause here until update is complete ...    

var names = db.GetCollection<MongoTest>("mongotest")
     .FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("name"))
     .ToList<MongoTest>();

if (names.Count() > 0)
{
     return View(names);
}
```

Comment: That's very strange as the MongoDb driver for .Net is synchronous and defaults to a write concern of `1`.  Is this just a single instance of MongoDb?

Comment: I would assume it's shared, but the db in question is one of 3 that I have hosted using MongoLab hosted version.  None are actively in production though, so I'm the only one hitting them.

Comment: Ouch... after you confirmed that the .NET driver was synchronous that guided my debugging down another path and I found that my code was swallowing an error.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One clarification. The official MongoDB .Net driver defaults to Acknowledged write (write concern 1) when you start with using MongoClient. If you start with the old style of using MongoServer.Create (now obsoleted), the default is Unacknowledged.
Also ensure that you are not using a read preference that could route your reads to a secondary.

Comment: On top of hiding an error, I was using the old syntax to instantiate my client.  Double whammy.  Thanks Sridhar!